# Creating a html game bot

Tags: node.js

I want to build a bot that basically inputs data and navigate/interacts with a specific website. However so far I've only found frameworks for chat bots and web crawlers. So I was wondering if there were any suitable framework for my needs, if someome can explain me what framework i need to use, thanks

Comment: Can you share what are your plans on this ? Any approach ?

Comment: Also, I'm afraid that NodeJs would not be the best tool to make a game that runs on the client-side (i.e. browser pages). You can try making a browser extension for it.

Comment: Nah, i dont want browser extension bcuz i want run it on virutal machine, and i can't find any good extension

Comment: have you tried anything like chromium or selanium ?

Comment: i do it with puppeteer,

Comment: I'm now looking for a web-bot framework for Node to use either with Selenium or Puppeteer, but it looks like there's nothing for this. After thinking more about it, it looks like a universal game bot framework would be hardly possible. It really depends on a game you're automating.